# 2D Array containing only 0 or 1

Tags: c, arrays

I have a 2 dimensional array which randomly contains values of 0 or 1.

How can I ( most efficiently ) determine the lower most element of value 1 ( the biggest row iteration i ) and the right most element ( the highest column iteration j ) ?

For example:

```
 0  0  1  0 
 1  0  1  0 
 0  1  0  0 
 1  0  0  0
```

My program should answer **i = 3** ( *assuming first row is i = 0*) and **j = 2** ( *assuming first column is 0* ).

Comment: Is it C or is it C++?

Comment: If matrix is a single block of memory and each cell is one byte then simply start searching from the end, backward.

Comment: Looks homeworkish :) . The fastest way I could think off the top of the mid it's done in O(n +m) where n is the number of rows and m is the number of columns (excluding the reading time). Rough search would be O(n*m).

Comment: @JohnZwinck I'm trying to get the program done in C, but if there's a tweak you are aware of in C++ please be kind and share it.

Comment: You can use a loop. In either language.

Comment: @user2079303 Yes, but my response time by using loop iteration is much higher than the standard I must accomplish.

Comment: What have you done? How long does it take? How long are you allowed?

Comment: How do you store your array? We need to know what you did already. You should be using bool to store each value, that will reduce the memory requirements and improve performance.

Comment: @RăzvanBarbu in that case you should probably improve your algorithm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an idea:

1. Starting with the bottom-most row, use `memrchr` to find the last `1` in each row (I'm sort of assuming you store the numbers as `char` aka 8-bit integers).
2. Eventually you will find a row which has a `1`.  This is your answer for `i`.  We got this far using cache-friendly, row-at-a-time operations because C uses row-major order.
3. Above, you also now know the lower bound for `j` (because you found the last `1` in the last row that had any `1`s).
4. For the remaining rows, use `memrchr` from one past the lower bound for `j` to the end of each row.  If you find any `1`s there, update the lower bound.  Repeat until you have inspected all the rows.
5. Of course, if you ever find a `1` in the last column, you can stop right away.

Answer (score 1):

Use a plain loop and simply search from the beginning (or the end, depending on what you want to achieve) and check each element. There is no more efficient way.

As far as C and C++ are concerned, what is efficient and what is not lies in the nature of the implementation. If this is a bit field matrix for example, then you can optimize the code slightly by first comparing each byte against 0, before you start searching through the individual bits.

And as usual, it doesn't make sense to talk about efficiency without specifying what it means. Speed? Memory consumption? Program size? It also doesn't make sense to talk about efficient implementation in C or C++ without a given system in mind.

Comment: @Lundind By efficiency I mean the lowest possible execution time.

Comment: @RăzvanBarbu Lowest possible execution time on what system?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the naive method - just iterating through all positions in the array. Worst case O(n*m):

```
#define WIDTH  4
#define HEIGHT 4

int main ()
{
    int i,j,col,row;
    int arr[HEIGHT][WIDTH] = set_Array();
    for (j=0;j<HEIGHT;j++){
        for (i = 0; i<WIDTH; i++){
            if (arr[j][i]){
                row = j>row?j:row;
                col = i>col?i:col;
    }}}
}
```

How can we improve this? Well we can start from the end and work backwards, but we will have to do the rows and columns alternately rather than just visiting each cell in turn. We could look for column, and then row, but that would be less efficient.

```
   0. 1. 2. 3.
0. 0  0  1  0 
1. 1  0  1  0
2. 0  1  0  0
3. 1  0  0  0
```

In this example, we search row `3` and column `3` first, and eliminate them from the search. Then row `2` and column `2` up to but not including the eliminated column `3` and row `3`. Then row `1`...
Of course, we stop searching rows when the bottom most one containing a `1` is found, and stop searching columns when the rightmost one containing a `1` is found.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define WIDTH  4
#define HEIGHT 4

int main ()
{
    int i,j,col = 0, row = 0;
    int current_row = HEIGHT;
    int current_col = WIDTH;
    int arr[WIDTH][HEIGHT] = {{0,0,1,0},{1,0,1,0},{0,1,0,0},{1,0,0,0}};
    while (!(row && col))
    {
         current_row--;
         current_col--;
         if (!row){
             printf("searching row: %d\n",current_row);
             for (i = 0; i < current_col; i++){
                 if (arr[current_row][i]){
                      row = current_row;
         }}}
         if (!col){
             printf("searching col: %d\n",current_col);
             for (j = 0; j < current_row; j++){
                 if (arr[j][current_col]){
                     col = current_col;
         }}}
    }
    printf("col: %d, row: %d\n", col, row);
}
```

<kbd>[**See it live**](http://ideone.com/njvsNp)</kbd>

Output:

```
searching row: 3
searching col: 3
searching col: 2
col: 2, row: 3
```

The worst case is still O(m*n), and is actually slightly worse (you test cells on the diagonal starting from the bottom right twice), but the average case is better.

We scan through the lowest unsearched row for a `1`, then search through the rightmost unsearched column for a `1`.
When you find the lowest `1` you no longer search each row for more `1`'s. When you find the rightmost `1` you no longer search each column for more `1`'s either.

This way we stop the search once we find the answer, and unlike the naive method, this means that we don't usually have to go through each value in the array.

Comment: Yes, well, unfortunately my array will be variable in size, and either way, 2 `for` loops each with an operation will result in a higher than needed execution time. I am looking for something similar to what @John Zwinck is suggesting. P.S.: i did not downvote :)

Comment: It's not the number of loops that matter, it is the algorithm.  Each of the `for` loops only deals with one line at a time, and as they are not nested, they will take O(n) and O(m) time instead of O(n*m) like you seem to think

Comment: You can easilly modify the array size by changing the `WIDTH` and `HEIGHT` to match the dimensions of your array (substitute in method/variable in their place).

Comment: @RăzvanBarbu this is the same algorithm, _very_ slightly different implementation

Comment: @RăzvanBarbu I've updated the algorithm with some `printf`s and added an ideone link so you can see how it works. Yes the array is hard coded right now, but you can change that in your code.

Comment: @RăzvanBarbu I've just updated the algorithm description a bit more

Answer (score 0):

If the row size of the array is up to 32 numbers you can use a single `int32_t` to represent a whole row: The value of the number is the whole row.
Then your whole array will be a one dimensional array of `int32_t`'s:

```
int32_t matrix[nRows];
```

Now you can find the lowermost row by finding the last number of `matrix` that is not equal to 0 in O(nRows) time with a very simple implementation.

Also, you can find the rightmost 1 by with the following trick:
For each `matrix[i]` you isolate the rightmost 1 by calculating `matrix[i] & -matrix[i]`. Then calculating the log2 of this result gives you the number of the column. The largest number of column for all `matrix[i]` numbers gives you the result you want. (Again O(nRows) time with a very simple implementation).

Of course, if the row size is larger that 32 values, you have to use more `int32_t` values per row, but the principle remains the same.